# mysql db structure for better performance

Tags: mysql

I'm not a professional, but I'm messing around with wordpress trying to customize it the way I want it to work...

I've a necessity to add additional data to single-posts, specifically a restaurant menu, each post will have unique menu displayed in sidebar.

Single post is a single row in wp_posts table.

[image: wp_posts]

I'm adding additional info using wp metabox functionality, which has its own table called wp_postmeta.

This table is different from wp_posts because it can contain many rows of meta information for a single post.

[image: wp_postmeta]

My questions:

Is this implementation slow?
Will it cause problems if db grows?
Why would wp guyz implement this in this way?
Would not it be wiser to have single meta column and multiple rows per post?

Comment: you need to display the structure of the DB and the tables

Comment: can't you understand from screenshots?

Comment: great attitude @ Sandro :) nice camera bro...

Comment: @SandroDzneladze did you check the links? you need to know how to apply a ERD (entity relationship diagram)

Comment: jcho360 yes I'm reading articles you have linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have "price_list_heading", `"price_list_category","price_list_heading1", "price_list_category1","price_list_heading2", "price_list_category2","price_list_heading3" and "price_list_category3"` I don't know why, but I think you shouldn't do that, you need to create a relational table with index (I don't know if Wordpress let you do that)

it'd will look like: this will depend of the cardinality of your APP

Let's say that 1 post meta can have multiple categories and multiple categories can be with one postmeta (cardinality N:M)

[image]

Now If one post can have multiple categories and one category can have only one post

[image]

Where wp_postmeta_copy1 is a FK from ws_postmeta table (id)

Please take a look to this documentation :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model
- http://www.inf.unibz.it/~franconi/teaching/2000/ct481/er-modelling/
- http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/entity-relationship-model